# Nginx SPA Serving Static Files, Proxying API Calls, and Rewriting to /index.html

Tags: nginx

So, I'd like to have an nginx.conf that...

1. Serves all /static requests directly
2. Proxies all /api requests to another local server (port 8200)
3. Serves /index.html for all other requests (so, /contact/123 would really serve /index.html)

Here is my current config...

```
server {
listen                      80;
server_name                 www.xyz.io;
root                        /opt/xyz/www;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
}

location @backend {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8200;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}
```

}

I'm really not clear how to have all other requests serve /index.html though.  Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
server {

   listen                      80;
   server_name                 www.xyz.io;
   root                        /opt/xyz/www;

   # index
   index index.html;

   # $uri, index.html
   location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }

   location /api {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8200;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
   }

}
```

Comment: That solved it.  Nice job.  Need to add a semi-colon to the end of the "index index.html" line though.